# ProviderError: evm: max code size exceeded - UniswapV2Router02

Tags: web3js, evm

|  UniswapV2Router02               ·     26.305  ·               │

`Warning: 1 contracts exceed the size limit for mainnet deployment.`

I'm trying to deploy on the EVM network, but this is a fork from UNISWAP, what can I do to deploy this contract without exceeding the size limit?

Comment: try running `optimizer` on your compiler

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at this tutorial V1 and then go to V2 .
This way you will understand how it works and then you can try to test it on rinkeby network first .
Hope this help , cheers !